# Dynamically display images on upload for multiple forms

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to display a an image as it's uploaded.

I have the following code, which works fine for a single form input:

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});

    <img width="50px" id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
```

However, I have multiple forms per page all with the same function in mind - each displaying an image once uploaded.

How can I make this work for multiple, dynamic forms?

Answer (score 1):

```js
function readURL(input) {
    var file = input.files[0];

    if(file)
    {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);

      reader.onload = function (e) {
          $(input).parents().find('img.blah').attr('src', e.target.result)
      }
    }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <img width="50px" class="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />

     <input type="file" id="imgInp" name="img" />
</div>
```